# UPPER in WHERE condition is not working in Apache Spark 3.5.0 for Mysql ENUM Column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have upgraded my spark job from spark 3.3.1 to spark 3.5.0, I am querying to Mysql Database and applying

`UPPER(col) = UPPER(value)`

in the subsequent sql query. It is working as expected in spark 3.3.1 , but not working with 3.5.0.

Where Condition ::

`UPPER(vn) = 'ERICSSON' AND (upper(st) = 'OPEN' OR upper(st) = 'REOPEN' OR upper(st) = 'CLOSED')`

The **st** column is ENUM in the database and it is causing the issue.

Below is the Physical Plan of **FILTER** phase :

For 3.3.1 :

```
+- Filter ((upper(vn#11) = ERICSSON) AND (((upper(st#42) = OPEN) OR (upper(st#42) = REOPEN)) OR (upper(st#42) = CLOSED)))
```

For 3.5.0 :

```
+- Filter ((upper(vn#11) = ERICSSON) AND (((upper(staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CharVarcharCodegenUtils, StringType, readSidePadding, st#42, 13, true, false, true)) = OPEN) OR (upper(staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CharVarcharCodegenUtils, StringType, readSidePadding, st#42, 13, true, false, true)) = REOPEN)) OR (upper(staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CharVarcharCodegenUtils, StringType, readSidePadding, st#42, 13, true, false, true)) = CLOSED)))
```

---

I have debug it and found that Spark added a property in version 3.4.0 , i.e. **spark.sql.readSideCharPadding** which has default value **true**.

Link to the JIRA :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-40697

Added a new method in Class **CharVarcharCodegenUtils**

```
public static UTF8String readSidePadding(UTF8String inputStr, int limit) {
    int numChars = inputStr.numChars();
    if (numChars == limit) {
      return inputStr;
    } else if (numChars < limit) {
      return inputStr.rpad(limit, SPACE);
    } else {
      return inputStr;
    }
  }
```

**This method is appending some whitespace padding to the ENUM values while reading and causing the Issue.**

---

When I am removing the UPPER function from the where condition the **FILTER** Phase looks like this :

```
 +- Filter (((staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CharVarcharCodegenUtils,      StringType, readSidePadding, st#42, 13, true, false, true) = OPEN         ) OR (staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CharVarcharCodegenUtils, StringType, readSidePadding, st#42, 13, true, false, true) = REOPEN       )) OR (staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CharVarcharCodegenUtils, StringType, readSidePadding, st#42, 13, true, false, true) = CLOSED       ))
```

**You can see it has added some white space after the value and the query runs fine giving the correct result.**

But with the UPPER function I am not getting the data.

---

I have also tried to disable this Property **spark.sql.readSideCharPadding = false** with following cases :

1. With Upper function in where clause :
   It is not pushing the filters to Database and the query works fine.

```
  +- Filter (((upper(st#42) = OPEN) OR (upper(st#42) = REOPEN)) OR (upper(st#42) = CLOSED))
```

2. **But** when I am removing the upper function

**It is pushing the filter to Mysql with the white spaces and I am not getting the data.**

```
  PushedFilters: [*IsNotNull(vn), *EqualTo(vn,ERICSSON), *Or(Or(EqualTo(st,OPEN         ),EqualTo(st,REOPEN       )),EqualTo(st,CLOSED       ))]
```

I cannot move this filter to JDBC read query , also I can't remove this UPPER function in the where clause.

Can anybody have any solution to fix this without changing my code.

Comment: Good analysis on your part. Certainly seems like a bug to me (a random lurker).

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula No , using Spark OpenSource

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, probably caused by the same bug.

Using **spark 3.5.0** for processing data from **MariaDB** with property `spark.sql.readSideCharPadding` set to **False**. It seems that the issue occurs when spark reads a db column of **enum** type.

There is an example case of this issue shown in the images bellow:

Even though the padding should be suppressed so the target value should be exactly `video_short`, I'm not able to use the filter in such trivial way.

[image: spark.sql.readSideCharPadding set to False]

In opposing situation, where I leave `spark.sql.readSideCharPadding` set to **True**, the behaviour is even more confusing. The value seems to be padded to `video_short`     , but the filter now works even without the padded spaces.

[image: spark.sql.readSideCharPadding set to True]